# How to solve $1-x = \frac{ax}{e^{ax}-1}$

Tags: laplace-transform, lambert-w

I am looking for an explicit solution to the equation

$$1-x = \frac{\alpha x}{e^{\alpha x} -1}$$

I tried this with the Lambert-W function but can't get a sensible solution. How would you approach this? And does a closed form solution exist for $\alpha \neq 1$?

For Lambert-W, I can only find a solution for $\alpha = 1$ where $$x = W\left(-\frac{1}{e} \right)+1$$
(I set $\alpha = 1$ for $(1-x)e^{\alpha x}-1+x = \alpha x$ which gives $(x-1)e^{x-1} = -\frac{1}{e}$ - then I apply Lambert W and get $$x = W\left(-\frac{1}{e}\right)+1$$

Comment: Can you show some of your attempt?

Comment: Maybe I’m inexperienced, but how would Laplace transform help?

Comment: @BenjaminWang no inherent reason but thought maybe it can be somehow simplified in Laplace space and the transformed back to yield a good solution.

Comment: Laplace transform is useful for differential equations.  But yours is not a differential equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$1-x=\frac{\alpha x}{e^{\alpha x}-1}$$
$$(1-x)(e^{\alpha x}-1)=\alpha x$$
$$(1-x)e^{\alpha x}-1+x=\alpha x$$

Your equation is an equation of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). For rational $\alpha$, the equation is related to an algebraic equation in dependence of $x$ and $e^x$. Because the terms $x,e^x$ are algebraically independent and the equation is irreducible, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).
A theorem of Lin (1983) proves, if Schanuel's conjecture is true, that irreducible algebraic equations involving both $x$ and $e^x$ don't have solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$$(1-x)e^{\alpha x}=\alpha x+1-x$$
$$(1-x)e^{\alpha x}=(\alpha-1)x+1$$
$$\frac{1-x}{(\alpha-1)x+1}e^{\alpha x}=1$$
$$\frac{1-x}{x+\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}e^{\alpha x}=\alpha-1$$

We see, your equation cannot be solved in terms of Lambert W but in terms of Generalized Lambert W:

$$\frac{x-1}{x+\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}e^{\alpha x}=1-\alpha$$
$$\frac{x-1}{x-\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}e^{\alpha x}=1-\alpha$$
$$x=W\left(^{\ \ \ 1}_{\frac{1}{1-a}};1-a\right)$$

The inverse relation of your kind of equations is what Mezö et al. call $r$-Lambert function. They write:
"Depending on the parameter $r$, the $r$-Lambert function has one, two or three real branches and so the above equations can have one, two or three solutions"

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 0):

The most I can get to is by setting $X=ax-a$:

$\begin{align}(1-x)(e^{ax}-1)=ax
&\iff -\frac 1a(ax-a)(e^ae^{ax-a}-1)=(ax-a)+a\\\\
&\iff-\frac 1aX(e^ae^X-1)=X+a\\\\
&\iff Xe^X=(1-a)e^{-a}X-a^2e^{-a}\end{align}$

But I don't think there is a general closed form for $Xe^X=\alpha X+\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ax=t$ and rewrite the equation as
$$e^{-t}=\frac 1 {1-a}\,\, \frac {t-a} {t-\frac a{1-a}}$$ which has a solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

Back to the original equation means that you are looking for the inverse of
$$a=1-\frac{1+W\left(e^{x-1} (x-1)\right)}{x}$$